# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gatsby, woocommerce-rest-api, gatsby-plugin

I am using wordpress website Local by flywheel ( url: xyz.local ) . I created a new gatsby site using and added gatsby-source-woocommerce. I also generated consumer key and consumer secret from woo-commerce settings. i added them to the api_keys in the config file.

When i run gastby develop, i get this error.

```
========== WARNING FOR FIELD products ===========
The following error status was produced: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
================== END WARNING ==================

08:19:23.204Z > gatsby-source-woocommerce: Fetching 0 nodes for field: products
08:19:23.206Z > gatsby-source-woocommerce: Completed fetching nodes for field: products
warn
========== WARNING FOR FIELD products/categories ===========
The following error status was produced: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
================== END WARNING ==================

08:19:23.213Z > gatsby-source-woocommerce: Fetching 0 nodes for field: products/categories
08:19:23.215Z > gatsby-source-woocommerce: Completed fetching nodes for field: products/categories
warn
========== WARNING FOR FIELD products/attributes ===========
The following error status was produced: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
================== END WARNING ==================
```

Can someone pls say if did i miss anything? or any wrong i have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Problem is with plugin.
In config options of gatsby-source-woocommerce,
comment everything after fields i.e After commenting it looks like,

```
{
      resolve: "@pasdo501/gatsby-source-woocommerce",
      options: {

        // Base URL of Wordpress site

        api: "wordpress.domain",

        // set to false to not see verbose output during build
        // default: true
        verbose: true,

        // true if using https. otherwise false.
        https: false,
        api_keys: {
          consumer_key: <key>,
          consumer_secret: <secret>,
        },
        // Array of strings with fields you'd like to create nodes for...
        fields: ["products", "products/categories", "products/attributes"],

       
      },
    },
```

Head to the @pasdo501/gatsby-source-woocommerce folder ( node modules ) -> gatsby-node.js
change api_version = "wc/v3" to "wc/v2" and
change wpAPIPrefix = null to "wp-json"
and save it.

voila

Answer (score 0):

no need to change the package. you can do this:

- add `/index.php` to the end of `api`.
- set `wpAPIPrefix` to `wp-json`.
- set `query_string_auth` to `true` (I,m not sure if this one necessary).

  ```
  {
    resolve: '@pasdo501/gatsby-source-woocommerce',
    options: {
      api: 'pro.com/index.php',
      https: true,
      verbose: true,
      api_keys: {
        consumer_key: `ck_...........`,
        consumer_secret: `cs_.................`,
      },
      fields: ['products', 'products/categories', 'products/attributes', 'products/tags'],
      wpAPIPrefix: 'wp-json',
      query_string_auth: true,
      api_version: 'wc/v3',
      // per_page: 100,
      // encoding: 'utf8',
      // axios_config: {}
    }
  }
  ```